# Replace empty XML tags in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xml

I was asked this question in an interview and wanted to know if anybody knows the best way to solve this.

I have an XML string and I don't have access to the entire XML document and the parser used is a streaming parser (NSXMLParser):

```
<i><b></b><strong>Test</strong></i>
```

This has to be replaced by

```
<i><b/><strong>Test</strong></i>
```

How do you do it in Objective-C using NSXMLParser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solved it and forgot to post the answer here:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

content = nil;
content = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

isEndElement = FALSE;

if([previousElement length] != 0){
    [previousAttribute count] != 0 ? NSLog(@"<%@ %@>", previousElement, [previousAttribute description]) : NSLog(@"<%@>", previousElement);
}

previousElement = elementName;
previousAttribute = attributeDict;
```

}

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

[content appendString:string];
```

}

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{     

previousElement = @"";

if(isEndElement){
    NSLog(@"</%@>", elementName);
}else{

    if([content length] != 0){
    [previousAttribute count] != 0 ? NSLog(@"<%@ %@>%@</%@>", elementName, [previousAttribute description], content, elementName) : 
                                                                                                    NSLog(@"<%@>%@</%@>", elementName, content, elementName);
    }else{        
        [previousAttribute count] != 0 ? NSLog(@"<%@ %@/>", elementName, [previousAttribute description]) : NSLog(@"<%@/>", elementName);
    }
}

isEndElement = TRUE;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There's not really "one" best way to do this, but Apple outlines some [general guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/ConstructingTrees.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002268-BCIEABEE) for modifying an XML document using `NSXMLParser`. It doesn't go into specifics and give you an exact implementation, but it should be somewhere for you to start.